# Magento 2.2.2 admin Shippings action View Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: orders, shipping, magento2.2.2

I am getting this weird one When an shipping is created then navigating to Shippings [image]

I the Action column when click view I get the error:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ../../../../htdocs/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/packaging/packed.phtml on line 12

I looked at the packed.html  and this is the line

```
<?php foreach ($block->getPackages() as $packageId => $package): ?>
```

I debug by:

```
print_r(gettype($block->getPackages())); RETURNS string 
print_r($block->getPackages()); RETURNS []
```

I am really confused I got dev environment which works fine and they return:

```
print_r(gettype($block->getPackages())); RETURNS array 
print_r($block->getPackages()); RETURNS Array()
```

There is definitely a difference there but what caused this not sure

Looking at teh:

```
Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Packaging
public function getPackages()
{
   return $this->getShipment()->getPackages();
}
```

PhpStorn inspection definitely complaint about return string when should return array Anyone have any idea is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the complete answer to the problem but it fix the shipping order page by the suppressing Warning e.g `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` at the packed.phtml But still doesn't make sense and I think it's a bug and hasn't been tested enough and if you have a solution please post your answer I would like to hear. thanks

Comment: Thank you. This worked on my setup Magento 2.2.5. Not sure what is the invalid argument though.